# "Action Mode" video in Swift application

Tags: ios, swift, video, ios-camera

I am using the AVCapture API and have tried all stabilization settings and video settings that I am aware of however I am unable to get the same quality of frames that Action Mode gets in the native iOS app during motion video.

How can I access the same API or settings that Action Mode uses within my app?